# Laravel Blade comment before "@if"

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Sometimes, in HTML, I need to avoid adding extra white space, but I also need to add "@if()" blocks. In order to accomplish this, I've taken this approach:

```
some text{--

--}@if($someCondition){--

--}more text with no space between

@endif
```

And this approach has been working great. However, after upgrading my development and live environments to Laravel 5.5 (from Laravel 5.2) the Development environment works fine, but the live environment renders the above blade into the following HTML:

```
some text@if($someCondition)more text with no space between

<?php endif; ?>
```

... So the "if" statement immediately after the blade comment is left as plain text.

I know that it's possible, because both my development environments render the page correctly. I've looked at PHP versions and copied over the entire code directory, but I cannot find any difference between them at all, let alone a difference that would cause this to be processed differently.

Is there any reason why Laravel's blade engine wouldn't allow a "@" right after blade comment?

Using PHP 7.029, Laravel 5.5, CentOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered the issue. The view was cached on the development environments, which is why it was working.

It looks like there was a new bug introduced in Laravel somewhere between 5.3 and 5.5. The blade comments are being removed before the rest of the blade is analysed, which can cause issues as I showed in the question here. This was working previously in Laravel 5.2.

I did find a work around:

```
some text{{null

}}@if($someCondition){--

--}more text with no space between

@endif
```

Produces something that works:

```
some text<?php echo e(null); ?><?php if($someCondition): ?>more text with no space between

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An *alternative* way to solve the original issue would be to *directly write some PHP code* for your if statements:

```
some text<?php

if($someCondition):

?>more text with no space between<?php
endif;
?>
```

(however, I agree this is not the sweatest way to write templates, as you will have a mix between Blade and PHP)

Laravel converts your blade templates into PHP, then use these converted files for rendering. So if you write directly some PHP code with your Blade templates, it will just work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Could always use the Blade native php enclosures...

```
some text{{ if(condition) {do something} }}more text
```

This gives the the flexibility of inline php with your HTML.