# Laravel Blade Php View: Is there a way to ignore any space before "@foreach @if" . etc?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, auto-indent

I am new to Laravel.
It seems like in default setting, the following code

```
    @foreach($foo as $bar)
    <div>
```

would generate 8 white spaces before the div in actual final html code.

I want to know is there a way to ignore the 4 spaces before the @foreach and only use the 4 spaces before the div?

A related but different question: [Laravel Blade comment before "@if"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49756554/laravel-blade-comment-before-if)
In this question the author seems to do what I am doing right now, which is essentially leave no space before the @foreach but the drawback is the source code looks ugly. Ideally there should be a way to make the code look nice while also not affecting the final output.

Comment: This happened to me a long time ago with Laravel, even my own framework, there is no "fix" for this as I am aware of, this is due to how it is "printed"

Comment: did you try inline ? `@foreach($foo as $bar)<div>@endforeach`

Comment: There are actually a lot of things between foreach and endforeach so the code would become much less readable using the inline method too.

Comment: Is this out of academic curiosity or do the spaces actually cause issues?

Comment: @apokryfos Both the "source code" and the "final html code" are huge, so readability is pretty much essential for faster debug. As it stands, I would have to sacrifice one for another.

Comment: Browser developer tools provide code autoformatting to fix these for you.